# Comment dit-on « May your journey be successful » en français?

Tags: expressions

Je veux souhaiter quelque chose à quelqu'un sur une carte cadeau. En anglais je lui aurait dit « May your journey be successful ».

J’ai cherché, mais je n'arrive pas à trouver une traduction fiable. Ma tentative est « Que ton voyage être réussi ». Est-ce que c'est correct ?

Comment: Merci pour tes reponses. Je suis intéressé plus le structure de phrase que le phrase particulier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Que souhaites-tu en réalité ? Le succès du *voyage* en lui-même (c'est-à-dire que la personne arrive effectivement là où elle veut aller) ou le succès d'un projet particulier que cette personne va mener et pour lequel elle se déplace (relativement) loin ?

Dans le premier cas (étrange mais toutefois possible), on pourrait souhaiter :

> Puisses-tu arriver à bon port ! (idiome n'impliquant pas le passage par un réel *port maritime*)

Mais je suppose que tu es plutôt dans le second cas, et il faudrait alors opter pour une proposition plus proche de la proposition de traduction littérale que propose à juste titre M42 (*Que ton voyage soit réussi*) ou une variante, comme :

> Que ton voyage soit fructueux !

ou

> Que ce voyage te soit profitable !

voire encore :

> Je te souhaite le meilleur succès pour ton voyage !

Comment: « Puisses-tu arriver à bon port » met l’accent sur l’arrivée : on ne souhaite pas que le *voyage* soit réussi, mais qu’il se *termine*. En fait, en lisant « puisses-tu arriver à bon port », je comprends « le voyage sera très certainement horrible, j’espère que tu arriveras sain et sauf ».

Comment: @Edouard En effet, c'est un risque avec cette formulation. Mais ce cas était déjà presque hors sujet, je ne l'ai ajouté que pour élargir le propos.

Answer (score 6):

La tournure la plus simple est peut être préférable :

> Bon voyage !

Pour en rajouter un peu, tu peux dire :

> Profites-en bien !
>   Profitez-en bien !

Ce dernier couvre mieux la notion de « successful » (~profitable).

Comment: Cette formulation alternative à l'impératif, même si elle s'éloigne de la traduction littérale, me plait bien. On pourrait même avoir *Profite bien de ton voyage !* pour reprendre l'ensemble des éléments en une seule phrase. C'est une formule très employée, même si elle met peut-être plus l'accent sur le plaisir que sur le succès.

Answer (score 3):

Tu pourrais aussi dire : "Je te souhaite un voyage plein de succès"

Comment: Pourquoi (-1) ? La proposition n'est pas mauvaise.

Answer (score 1):

Tu y es presque, la phrase correcte est :

> Que ton voyage *soit* réussi.

Comment: Ça sonne quand même bizarrement. « Que ton voyage réussisse », ou les alternatives proposées par Romain, me semble de meilleurs choix.